# Using a Map as the RequestBody for a Spring AJAX request (using ExtJS)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, extjs

I am trying to make an AJAX call from ExtJS to a Spring 3.1.3 backend, using PUT and with a Map as a request parameter.  I can successfully make a similar call using a List param and passing a JavaScript array of strings, but cannot get a Map to work using a JavaScript object.

In other words, this works:

```
@RequestMapping(value="stringTest", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody String stringTest(@RequestBody List<String> list) {
    //do stuff
    return "OK";
}

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "stringTest",
    method: 'PUT',
    jsonData: ['one','two'],
    success: function() { console.log('ok'); },
    failure: function(){ console.log('fail'); }
});
```

However, this does not work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="mapTest", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody String mapTest(@RequestBody Map<String,String> map) {
    //do stuff
    return "OK";
}

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "mapTest",
    method: 'PUT',
    jsonData: {one: 'one', two: 'two'},
    success: function() { console.log('ok'); },
    failure: function(){ console.log('fail'); }
});
```

The request itself does not fail (no 400 error), but the map itself is empty when the mapTest method is instantiated.

One curious point I have discovered is that I am able to make this work using both `jsonData` **and** `params` (but **not** one or the other) as part of the `Ext.Ajax.request`, like this:

```
var data = {one: 'one', two: 'two'};
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "mapTest",
    method: 'PUT',
    jsonData: data,
    params: data,
    success: function() { console.log('ok'); },
    failure: function(){ console.log('fail'); }
});
```

However, I can't use this approach because I cannot have the extra parameters passed as part of the URL string, which is what this ends up doing.

So, the question is, how can I use a Map as my request param, using just `jsonData` for the request body?

Comment: What Spring MVC version are you on? Can you open your browser's network console and check what gets sent in the request? Please post that.

Comment: This is using Spring 3.1.3 for all Spring libraries.  In the Chrome Network tab, the Request Payload is sent exactly as you'd expect: {"one":"one","two":"two"}